# http header request with random parameter

Tags: header, http-method

I have received many http header request with **random** parameter in my web server like :
HEAD /?723 HTTP/1.1
\host: sample
\accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
\content-length: 0
\Connection: close

Does any one know if they are valid or not? i want to know if my server is the target of attack!

Comment: What is the user-agent?

Comment: this is the full request I have received, there is no user-agent in it! how may I find it?

Comment: If it appears, it will be one of the HTTP headers, but I guess you did not get it. Are you able to identify the IP address from which request came? You might get some clue by doing a whois search of the requestor's IP address. HEAD requests are usually used for checking broken links.